# How to pass the item's value into dictionary while sending the POST request in Python?

Tags: python, json, post, request, python-requests

I have the following code:

```
import requests 
import json
import urllib2

data = '{"userId":"ediscovery111@gmail.com","password":"4-53bAGK"}'
response = requests.post(url, data=data,  headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"})
dataa =  json.loads(response.content)
tiketId = dataa['token_type'] + dataa['access_token']
print tiketId
```

tiketId is `bearer7797d2bf-7cd2-4484-b934-77b9031c119b`.

Now I want to make a POST request with the following code:

```
data = '{"name":"t", "workspaceId":"0917dbfd-228c-4b07-a7ed-a9812169b878"}'
response = requests.post(createfolder, data=data, headers={"Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization":"tiketId"} )
data1 = json.loads(response.content)
print data1
```

It gives me the following error:

> An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext" while posting the data.

I want to send the `tiketId` value (`bearer7797d2bf-7cd2-4484-b934-77b9031c119b`) but only passing `"ticketId"` in a dictionary as a value of Authorization, does not work.

How can I pass the value of `tiketId` in the Authorization key.

Comment: although i have been importing the following module:                                          import requests
                                                                                                        import json
                                                                                                         import urllib2

Comment: Don't leave a comment; edit the question instead.

Comment: Please can any one have solution of this problem?

Comment: Did you look at the related questions on the right? They may shed some light on your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that you use the string `"tiketId"` instead of the variable `tiketId` containing the string you built.

So you should use

```
response = requests.post(createfolder, data=data, headers={"Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization":tiketId} )
```

instead of

```
response = requests.post(createfolder, data=data, headers={"Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization":tiketId} )
```

**EDIT** after the comment spot the problem was the confusion between variable and string

Comment: HI Xavier,i want to pass the ticketId's value into the Authorization key as a value which is under the headers while posting the request.